# Check number range in a string using regex?

Tags: regex

I've a string such as `p-1-text-20` and I want to check the last digit after `-` is between 10 to 25.

Is it possible to write a regexp for this?

Comment: Is it possible to have `p-1-text-020` or `p-1-text-20.5` as values?

Comment: it could be anything from 1-1000+

Comment: @codef0rmer I don't think that answers Alex's question... It's specifically about leading zeros and decimals, not the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need a regex for checking if the number is greater than 10, you could say:

```
-[1-9][0-9]{1,}$
```

---

As per your updated post (check the last digit after `-` is between 10 to 25), you could use the following regex:

```
-([1][0-9]|[2][0-5])$
```

Comment: May be some symbols between `-` and `digit`. I think will be better to add `[^-]*`: `-[^-]*[1-9][0-9]{1,}$`

Comment: @devnull: I've updated the question to check the range.

Comment: @devnull: Almost there. I want to make it dynamic so the range could be anything like 2 to 20. How would your second regex change?

Comment: @codef0rmer That is basic problem with regex, you'd need to tweak it if you were to change ranges.  For 2 to 20, you could say `([2-9]|1[0-9]|20)`.